# Is the keeping of several booleans as state variables a bad programming practice?

Tags: design-patterns, boolean, state-pattern

Suppose we have a complex class that interfaces with several different other objects, and these interactions depend on the states of one another.

Immediately I would attempt to use several state booleans to try and keep track of these states, but this often leads to messy code filled with IF statements.

Are there settled solutions or design patterns to handle this while minimizing the messiness?

As an example, consider something like this:

```
int Foo(int A, int B, inc C)
{
    if(_state1 && !_state2)
        return A+B;

    else if(_state1 && _state2 && _state3)
        return A+C;

    else if(!_state1 && (_state4 || _state5)
        return C;    
    ...
}
```

It's easy to see how something like this would run out of control very quickly

Comment: the state pattern comes to mind, but your question is too vague. You' better post the code so that we see how to improve it.

Comment: There's no specific sample, it's just something I've encountered several times now. I'll try and get an example though

Comment: Are you talking about something where you have a sequence of state variables like `is_ready_for_method_a`, `is_ready_for_method_b`, etc? In that case, you'd be looking for a state machine.

Comment: Something like that. I've added a sumb example to make it a bit clearer (hopefully). I'll take a look at state machines

Answer (score 1):

Likely, one of the better ways to implement this would be with a state machine, depending on details that weren't provided. (I'm going to give my example in Java because that's what I'm familiar with and you didn't specify; however, it should be applicable to most OO languages.)

You'd want an enumeration, a state variable, and to use a switch statement to choose.

So, you'd want an enum:

```
public static enum ExampleState {
    // You would want explanatory names in a real program.
    INITIAL_STATE, SOME_STATE, OTHER_STATE
}
```

And then, on your complex class:

```
private ExampleState state = ExampleState.INITIAL_STATE;

public int foo(int a, int b, int c) {
    switch (state) {
    case INITIAL_STATE: return a + b;
    case SOME_STATE: return a + c;
    case OTHER_STATE: return c;
    default: throw new IllegalStateException("Unexpected state " + state);
    }
}
```

For a normal state machine, you'd also want methods like

```
public void changeStateInSomeSpecificWay() {
    switch (state) {
    case INITIAL_STATE:
        someAction();
        state = SOME_STATE;
        break;
    case SOME_STATE:
        someOtherAction();
        state = INITIAL_STATE;
        break;
    case OTHER_STATE:
        someThirdAction();
        state = INITIAL_STATE;
        break;
    default:
        throw new IllegalStateException("Unexpected state " + state);
    }
}
```